# How to store a python dict in Postgresql hstore

Tags: python, postgresql, hstore

I would like to store this kind of dict in hstore. Is it supported by hstore?

```
dict= {'fieldnames':['type', 'precision', 'width', 'data']}
```

If not, is there a way to flatten that structure to make it supported by hstore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'd want to do is write a wrapper on the field that will stringify nested data on writes and the de-serialize that info when you read it back.

e.g. you want to store it like this:

```
{"fieldnames" : "['type', 'precision', 'width', 'data']"}
```

you can do it using `json.dumps:`

```
{"fieldnames" : json.dumps(['type', 'precision', 'width', 'data'])}
```

Comment: Not really, I would like to know if I could use this kind of dict in hstore, so I could access 'type' or 'data' individually for a 'fieldname'

Comment: Maybe I would have to create four hstore column, like {'fieldname:'type'} | {'fieldname:'precision'} | {'fieldname:'width'} | {'fieldname:'data'}

Comment: you want to use the [json data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-json.html) if you want nested data. hstore only provides a flat data structure.

Comment: hstore can now store keys that contain arrays as values. it is a perfectly acceptable type for the question asked.